# How can I extract the equation of this special cylindir?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates

[image]

there is an equation I could not figure out. As you see, in the drawing above, there is a shape in polar coordinate. The radius of the disc changes according to the angle.

$\ r(0) = 0 $, and as the angle θ increase, radius r increases as well. But as you noticed, increase of radius has to be in a way that the angle between the tangent of the surface and orthogonal to the center must be always a predetermined constant(Q1).

This is what I've done so far:

$\  r(θ+Δθ)  = \frac{r(θ)}{cos(Δθ) - sin(Δθ)cot(Q_1)}  $ when $\ Δθ \rightarrow 0 $

I could not achieve to complete the equation and find $\ r(θ) = ? $

Comment: Are you sure it is $r(0)=0$? I don't see how you can have a constant angle $Q_1$ around $r(0)=0$... If $r(0)>0$, I may have a suggestion, but I need to verify that it works.

Comment: @N.Bach If r(0) can be zero (0) it would be really nice. Why do you think r(0) can't be zero? You can think like $ Δθ > 0 $

Comment: Try to make your drawing at $\theta=0$, because $r(0)=0$ you can't really define the lines or triangles to measure the angle between $r(0)$ and $r(\Delta\theta)$, so basically at that point I don't understand how you can enforce $Q_1$ to be constant... If you prefer, I understand your definition of $Q_1$ only from the drawing, and when $r(\theta)$ becomes $0$ it becomes undefined so I'm not sure what your constraint means anymore...

Comment: If you prefer, let $c(\Delta\theta,Q_1)=\cos(\Delta\theta)-\sin(\Delta\theta)\cot(Q_1)$, your formula can be rewritten as $r(\theta)=c(\Delta\theta,Q_1)r(\theta+\Delta\theta)$. This means that for any integer $n$, you get $r(0+n\Delta\theta)=r(n\Delta\theta)=c(\Delta\theta,Q_1)^nr(0)=0$ and your radius always goes back to $0$, and most likely is constant equal to $0$.

Comment: Suggestion: I haven't checked your equation, but up to terms of order two in $\Delta\theta$,$$r(\theta + \Delta\theta) = r(\theta) + r'(\theta)\, \Delta\theta.$$Alternatively, parametrize your curve as $\mathbf{x}(\theta) = r(\theta)(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ with $r$ an unknown function, and express the defining condition as $$\frac{\mathbf{x}(\theta) \cdot \mathbf{x}'(\theta)}{\|\mathbf{x}(\theta)\|\, \|\mathbf{x}'(\theta)\|} = \cos Q_{1}.$$Straightforward algebra gives an easily-solved differential equation for $r$.

Comment: I quickly tried your alternative version with the scalar product, with some additional assumption I end up with an exponential, which comforts my intuition that $r(0)$ should be non zero.